# Select empty element in <select> with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I use AngularJS and bind a `<select>` to my model:

```
<select ng-model="model.something" ng-options="..." >
    <option></option>
</select>
```

It leaves one empty element on top of dropdown, and then generates other options from my view-model.

These things work great: 
1. I choose option from dropdown, it is bound to `model.something`.
2. I choose empty option, `model.something` is set to `null`.
3. I set `model.something` in another function, the correct option is selected.

What does not work:
  - I set `model.someting` to `null` in another function, empty option is not selected, the previous value is still selected. 
**How to "tell" Angular to select empty option, if I bind model to `null` value?**

Answer (score 4):

Change `<option></option>` to `<option value=""></option>` and set `model.someting` to empty string `""`.

**UPDATE**

Here is a working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/6kLW6/

Comment: Can value be set to `null`, not `''`? When user selects empty, it effectively means, that they want to "delete" their previous decision. I need the value to be `null` then.

Comment: I use it this way in my applications and it works; empty string, effectively, makes the value "undefined" i.e. not selected. I'll check setting it to "null" or "undefined" in JSFiddle and get back to you.